# Pyglet not drawing scheduled function

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

Okay, so I'm a complete novice to both pyglet and OpenGL generally, I'm wondering why this doesn't work:

```
def DrawCircle(cx, cy, r, segments):

theta = 2*3.1415926/segments
c = math.cos(theta)
s = math.sin(theta)

x = r
y = 0

pyglet.gl.glBegin(pyglet.gl.GL_POLYGON)
pyglet.gl.glColor3f(0.05,0.2,0.9)
for counter in range(segments):
    pyglet.gl.glVertex2f(x+cx, y+cy)
    t = x
    x = c * x - s * y
    y = s * t + c * y
pyglet.gl.glEnd()

if __name__ == '__main__':
window = pyglet.window.Window(960,1010)
window.set_location(959,20)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()

def update(dt):
    print(dt)
    DrawCircle(500,500,20,30)

pyglet.clock.schedule_once(update,0.6)    
pyglet.app.run()
```

Put simply, if I call DrawCircle from on_draw it creates a circle exactly as desired. If I schedule it nothing gets drawn. The scheduler itself is working because dt prints to console. I'm guessing that on_draw is setting the context or something which allows it to draw whereas when I schedule it the context or perhaps the buffer is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `window.switch_to()` above the draw call and `window.flip()` after in the update function.

Although, as mentioned in msarch's answer, you should avoid drawing in an update funcion and let the on_draw function handle it.

Comment: Hmmm, I have previously tried window.switch_to() and it doesn't seem to fix the problem. To clarify, I'm just testing with schedule_once... I eventually intend on writing a basic particle simulator and want to repeatedly redraw the circle (which will represent a particle). Perhaps this is a hard way of doing it but given how simple the eventual visual would be I thought it wouldn't matter.

Comment: If it is double buffering you also have to add `window.flip()` at the end of the update function.

Comment: Aha, I had tried that when I was haphazardly trying to fix the problem, I had however not thought to try them together. Of course now I understand why everyone just uses on_draw, because everything needs to be redrawn anyway as, so far as I can tell, there is no way of idling in an update loop until the next update. Anyway I've got a better idea of how the event loop works now and how to ensure buffering + context is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the correct code :

```
import pyglet
import math

window = pyglet.window.Window(960,1010)
window.set_location( 50,50)

def DrawCircle(cx, cy, r, segments):

    theta = 2*3.1415926/segments
    c = math.cos(theta)
    s = math.sin(theta)

    x = r
    y = 0

    pyglet.gl.glColor3f(0.05,0.2,0.9)
    pyglet.gl.glBegin(pyglet.gl.GL_POLYGON)

    for counter in range(segments):
        pyglet.gl.glVertex2f(x+cx, y+cy)
        t = x
        x = c * x - s * y
        y = s * t + c * y

    pyglet.gl.glEnd()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    DrawCircle(500,500,20,30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyglet.app.run()
```

With Pyglet, all the drawings is usually done in the on_draw method.
Since you clear the window at every redraw, you also have to draw your shape every time.

An update function isn't necessarily related to display

Scheduling once or at regular interval is generally used to modify various parameters on a regular interval basis (ie: x,y += dx,dy *dt for animation).

see [:http://pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.clock-module.html](http://pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.clock-module.html)

Comment: As I said below I do intend on eventually making an animation by constantly redrawing the circle. Perhaps I'd be better off using a sprite. In any case what I eventually want to achieve is this: Start off drawing a "cage", ideally this wouldn't need to be redrawn constantly. Then add a small ball inside the cage whose position will constantly be updated. I'm not sure I understand the event handler, but I thought putting the cage in on_draw (which I've already done) and putting the circle in an update function would be how this is done.

Comment: the circle and the cage are drawn at each frame by on_draw(). The update of the circles coordinates happens at the rate you chose in another function which you call with the clock.schedule method at the rate you specify.

Comment: Yeah, I was under the misapprehension that the on_draw was only called at the beginning. I realized I was wrong when after implementing ebbs' solution the circle immediately disappeared as on_draw was dispatched again. Anyway it was useful to learn what on_draw was doing in the background with regard to flipping the buffer etc.